# How to install python3.5 or 3.6 in linux that has python 3.4

Tags: linux, python-3.x, virtualenv

I want to  install python 3.5 in linux that has   python 3.4 
via virtualenv or any other mean.
since the system version is 3.4 ,I don't want to upgrade it so the system don't crash .

Comment: You can find a deb/rpm repo somebody maintains for your system. But be careful. They have to keep to the python3.5 naming convention and not write a `python3` link to their own stuff. I used a PPA for 3.6 on a machine with 3.5 native that wasn't good at maintaining discipline and have a real mess on my hands.

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo apt-get install package python3` should install the latest version of Python, and remove the older one.